# nodejs Replace a characrer into a new line

Tags: node.js

Hello I have a string like this

```
"Login Test ,Close browser"
```

I want to replace the , and make it return to new line like this :

```
"Login Test 
Close browser"
```

I tried

```
       let newString2 = newString.replace(/,/g, '\n');
```

But it doesnt work
Any solution please

Comment: Your regex works OK for me

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, as you can see by running this snippet:

```js
const newString = "Login Test ,Close browser";
let newString2 = newString.replace(/ *,/g, '\n');
console.log(newString2);
// Login Test
// Close browser
```

Comment: I'm storing a result in mongodb using mongoose, to display it in angular .. when i put the variable  <tr >{{event.run}}</tr> that contains the string I need it all shows in the same line

Comment: what? isn't that the opposite of what you asked? Also, did this solution not work for you?